# Weighted Least Squares -- zero mean for error makes sense, but why require zero mean for measurements?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares

In *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, Strang shows \hat{x} from equation 12 in the attached screenshot is the best linear unbiased estimator for A**x** = **b**. One of the assumptions used to derive \hat{x} is that "each right side b<sub>i</sub> has mean zero" (see blue highlights)

Is this a typo? I get that the error (**b** - A**x**)<sub>i</sub> has mean zero but why would b<sub>i</sub> have mean zero also? It is easy to imagine a sample of measurements where all the measurements are positive (e.g., a doctor measures your heart rate three times) and thus do not have mean zero

[image]

Comment: Also how do I get the x hat notation to work here? Web searches suggested \hat{x} but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: type `$\hat{x}$` (i.e. enclose the LaTeX math mode markup in `$   $` symbols before and after) and MathJax will convert it for you, like so: $\hat{x}$